# Is it possible to deny access to copied password field in database?

Tags: python, django, security

My Django app password in database looks like this:

```
pbkdf2_sha256$100000$XXXXXXXXXX$XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But if I duplicate it to another user, I could log in to that user's account.

Assuming a database breach or some kind of injection, can I detect if password was somehow duplicated/copied so that I can deny access to the account or alert admins?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking - do you want to restrict users to have unique passwords, or detect when the database is compromised?

Comment: You can check the DB for duplicates or prevent them with a constraint. But frankly that would mitigate only one of thousands of possible attack vector if you have an injection. So, you have to prevent the injection in the first place.

Comment: If someone has write access to your user database this will be the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Selcuk says if some one has access to write into your database, he/she can do anything like generate password as your system want.

but you can make it harder to change password.

if you want to deny password copy from database you must create your own user model and update hashing algorithm like this.

first create a user model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password
class MyUser(User):
    def set_password(self, raw_password):
      self.password = make_password(self.username + raw_password)
      self._password = raw_password

   def check_password(raw_password):
      def setter(raw_password):
          self.set_password(raw_password)
          self._password = None
          self.save(update_fields=['password'])
      return check_password(self.username + raw_password, self.password. setter)
```

by these changes user password hashes are contain username and copy hash for other user does not works correctly